# Bulk complete several Confluence inline-tasks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, confluence

I am trying to write a Confluence user macro that will mark all tasks on the current page as complete.
However, I am not able to find the correct object to simluate the click event on.
Simulating a click on the <ul> or <li> does not work, as the checkbox itself is just a background-image.
Is it somehow possible to target that image with js?

Here's what I have so far (If I click this, nothing happens):

```
## Macro title: Check All Tasks
## Macro has a body: N
## Date created: 2022-07-08
## Installed by: R.
## @noparams

<a id="toggleAll" href="#">Check all tasks</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
AJS.toInit(function () {
    AJS.$('#toggleAll').click(function() {
        // first try
        jQuery('[role="checkbox"]').each(function(){ jQuery(this).trigger("click");})

        // another try with querySelector
        document.querySelectorAll('[role="checkbox"]').forEach(function (el){
        el.click();});
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's the relevant html/css from a typical task:

```
<td><ul class="inline-task-list" data-inline-tasks-content-id="122741856" role="group">
<li data-inline-task-id="2" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" class="">
<span class="placeholder-inline-tasks">My Task</span>
</li></ul></td>
```

```
ul.inline-task-list>li {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTQiIGhlaWdodD0iMTQiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiPjxkZWZzPjxyZWN0IGlkPSJhIiB3aWR0aD0iMTQiIGhlaWdodD0iMTQiIHJ4PSIyIi8+PC9kZWZzPjxnIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0iZXZlbm9kZCI+PHVzZSBmaWxsPSIjRkFGQkZDIiB4bGluazpocmVmPSIjYSIvPjxyZWN0IHN0cm9rZT0iI0E1QURCQSIgeD0iLjUiIHk9Ii41IiB3aWR0aD0iMTMiIGhlaWdodD0iMTMiIHJ4PSIyIi8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to simulate the click event on the `span.placeholder-inline-tasks` ?

Comment: I just tried that, but doesn't work either.

Comment: They may not use an event listener triggered by a click simulation, maybe you should try an other solution. If you add an `eventListener` that print something in the console you'll see that your code trigger the click. I presume if it doesn't check the task it means they use a specific way to verify if the checkbox is clicked by an humain ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my specific problem.
This Confluence macro basically does what I want to achieve: https://gist.github.com/leecannon/f38d1b0288f3a68a0461d2ea6da3bda3

But knowing that I can complete tasks using the REST API, I wrote a bash script instead which is more flexible than a user macro. And I can just feed it a list of content/task-ids.

Here's the relevant curl command if anyone else needs it:

```
curl -u user:password -k -s --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{ "status": "CHECKED", "trigger": "VIEW_PAGE" }' \
$conf_url/rest/inlinetasks/1/task/$contentid/$taskid/
```

You can get contentid and taskid from the database table "AO_BAF3AA_AOINLINE_TASK", or from the Confluence page itself (right-click on task, inspect element, and look for the classes 'data-inline-tasks-content-id' and 'data-inline-task-id')